# 13.10 how to remove COMPLETELY facebook?

Tags: uninstall

I've accidently installed facebook appplication, while accidently clicking on popup on firefox.
I've tried to remove it by deleting files from some directories, like /usr/share/applications, but it's still there, and not only, now it causes firefox to crash.
It happens when I launch facebook from browser, then this annoying thing launches, then firefox crushes.
I've removed .png icon of facebook, but it seems that it 'auto-generates'?? it pops up when I connect to facebook on the browser. it starts to be scary and everytime I see the thing comes out, I want to puke or something.

I've tried search on google and tried this:
sudo apt-get autoremove $(dpkg -l | grep facebook | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')

and this removed my qjack install. hahaha.

can someone please guide me to TOTALLY GET RID OF FACEBOOK?
I mean, COMPLETELY.
at least can somebody tell me where it is hidden?

additionally, it'd be amazing if someone can tell us about the way to block facebook communicate with my machine.

I bought brand new computer only a few days ago, after hard working months to save money. Big part of this purchase is to enjoy the new version of Ubuntu 13.10 and unity...etc.
All this joy is ruined by dirty spyware installed by forcing me to make mistake and insist to stay on my machine.

Please help me!!!!!

Comment: How did you install?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to enter the online accounts menu and delete your facebook account, you can also disable the websites integration addon in Firefox.

Comment: not at all, I don't even have facebook account in online account menu. if it was so easy I wouldn't ask here. thanks for reply anyway.